# How to rename and exposes a type from the 3rd party dll

Tags: c#, .net-assembly

Is there a way for a custom assembly to rename and exposes a type from the 3rd party dll?

```
// Assembly Foo (cannot change code)
namespace Foo
{
    enum XValues
    {
        Val1, Val2;
    }
}

// Assembly Bar
// References Foo
namespace Bar
{
    using Foo;
    // Code that exposes Foo.XValues as Bar.YValues
}

// Assembly Client
// References Bar
namespace Client
{
    void Main() {
        Console.WriteLine(Bar.YValues.Val1);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there a way for a custom assembly to rename and exposes a type from the 3rd party dll?

No, is the short answer. A type is a type is a type. You could create your *own* enum in `Bar` which has the same values, and convert between them where you need to.

What are you trying to achieve - what's the bigger picture? There may well be a better solution than the one you're thinking of.

Comment: I am trying to make a stable interface that can be distributed with an unstable interface without having to wrap every type initially.

Comment: @Josh: I don't think there's a solution to that, really. Just go for the wrapping.